# In what sense are proofs that rely on the Law of the Excluded Middle really proofs?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

As a non-mathematician, it seems to me that the Law of Excluded Middle is merely an axiom when it comes to proofs that employ it.

Can we really rely on such proofs?  In what sense are they valid?

**EDIT**

In the light of comments, my point is that yes, all proofs depend on axioms (I believe - I have never proved anything myself!) but, if we want to prove something in a specific field, how can we be certain that a proof is valid?

For example, I understand that there were mistaken proofs concerning factorisation because it was not realised that it was necessary to take into account complex numbers.

Therefore the main part of my question (i.e. In what sense are they valid?) really means, **How does one decide whether or not this axiom is relevant in a particular field.**

Comment: Look up Intuitionistic logic

Comment: Perhaps this is a question for https://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Comment: How about proofs that do not rely on the Law of the Excluded Middle? Are they really proofs?  What about proofs that rely on the law of disjunctive inference or conjunction elimination or modus ponens?  Those are merely axioms.  As a non-mathematician, what do you think a proof is?

Comment: That's the case for every axiom. Validity comes from the fact that systems with the Law of Excluded Middle produce interesting, and deep structures.

Comment: The edit made the question even less clear than before: you are now asking 3 very different questions.

Comment: You might enjoy reading Imre Latakos’ little book _Proofs and Refutations_.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan - I suppose so. That is the danger of asking a question with limited knowledge and then trying to revise the question to take account of comments. If I had known everything that everyone would say ahead of asking, I would have formulated the question differently. I'm not sure whether to simply write a new question and start again, or to stick with what I have.

Comment: "I have never proved anything myself!" To gain some insights into the most basic methods of proof, may I humbly suggest working through the tutorial that it is included with my proof-checking freeware available at my homepage http://www.dcproof.com

Answer (score 6):

That depends on what you define as "valid".

Most mathematicians work with classical logic, i.e. logic in which the law of excluded middle is an accepted axiom. As David pointed out in the comment, there is also intuitionistic logic, in which the law of excluded middle is not accepted as axiom.

Since most mathematicians work with classical logic, most modern mathematical results are proved with the law of excluded middle assumed as an axiom. Thus, these proofs are "valid" in classical logic. On the other hand, if a proof uses the law of excluded middle somewhere (e.g. proof by contradiction), then it is not a "valid" proof in intuitionistic logic.

In summary, there is no single property determining whether a proof is "valid". Instead, we can only ask if a proof is valid in a certain class of logic.

Comment: Thank you. While you were answering, I was adding a rider to my question. I don't think this invalidates your answer but I hope it explains my question better.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica My knowledge of the history of mathematics is limited, but I believe there isn't a good answer rather than "that's just what mathematicians in the past have decided on". Naturally, assuming fewer axioms means that we can produce fewer results that are interesting. On the other hand, we do not want to assume too many axioms unnecessarily, so a balance has to be struck. It just turns out that the law of excluded middle is an axiom that mathematicians decided to keep.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I have not read much of the content, but you may find this post helpful: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7633/what-is-the-origin-of-law-of-excluded-middle

Answer (score 2):

Answering,

" How does one decide if the law of excluded middle, is relevent to one's field"

There is quite a bit of work, often done by logistician-mathematicians that attempts to show what is provable with the least assumptions possible.

finding the weakest set of axioms needed to prove x.

I would say there isn't a general rule, for knowing if one needs a certain axiom or not. It's case by case.

Law of Excluded middle lets you employ proof by contradiction arguments, which work even when you can't build an example of what you are proving.

So, if there is some theorem saying you can't ever construct x, but you want to prove something about it.... there's a decent chance you will need the Law of Excluded Middle.

Comment: Thanks. That last sentence in particular gives me food for thought.